# 1 Peter 1:5. Does it teach the perseverance of the Saints

Tags: soteriology, 1-peter

> 1Pe 1:5 BLB who are being guarded by the power of God through faith,
> for the salvation ready to be revealed in the last time,

This States so strongly that we are Kept as in a garrison by the Power of God through faith.

**Whose Faith?**

For if it is our faith, that will mean our faith can determine if we will be Saved. And God guards us through it.

What does this passage mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious answer to the OP's question is "Yes"; 1 Peter 1:5 teaches perseverance of the saints.  However, there are at least two diametrically opposed views about what this doctrine means:

- In Calvinism, it means that God chooses who will be saved and that such saints cannot be lost, ie, God miraculous makes the saints persevere.
- In Arminianism, it means that God miraculous chooses to protect the saints according to their faith, which means that the saint has the freedom to opt out.

[Note: Calvinism is not monolithic and there are degrees of Calvinism (whether "5-point", 4 point" or something else); however, that defined above is what John Calvin taught - see appendix below.]

The form of "perseverance of the saints" cannot be determined from 1 Peter 1:5 alone - that must be found from other NT teaching.  All than can be said of 1 Peter 1:5 is that divine protection and perseverance of the saints is taught; but the details are not in this verse.

**APPENDIX - Calvinism**

In his 1537 Instruction in Faith, John Calvin says:

> “For, the seed of the word of God takes root and brings forth fruit
> only in those whom the Lord, by his eternal election, has predestined
> to be children and heirs of the heavenly kingdom.  To all the others
> (who by the same counsel of God are rejected before the foundation of
> the world) the clear and evident preaching of truth can be nothing but
> an odour of death unto death.”

Paul T Fuhrmann tr., 1949, p. 36

Comment: This is a very good Answer.  I'd like a full scriptural presentation on the perseverance of the Saints.   If you have any link

Comment: @FaithMendel - See https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/52537/who-is-the-we-in-hebrews-23/52544#52544  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/73950/2-timothy-217-19-and-god-s-foundation/73964#73964  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/76198/are-john-151-11-and-revelation-314-22-referring-to-the-same-group-of-people/76199#76199  I you post an email, I will send something.

Comment: Okay.  Is it safe to post an email here ?

Comment: @FaithMendel - that is up to your judgement.  You can delete it after I note it if you prefer.

Comment: Our profile is supposed to have some sort of inbox.  Stack exchange should work on it.

Comment: I'd prefer a social media handle.  So I can dm

Comment: I have often lamented that SX does not have an inbox to send private message that can be deleted in (say) seven days.  I agree that this would be a great extra to maintain people's preferred anonymity.